# Laravel: Storing an array of 3 strings inside one column of a table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am wondering what the best way to accomplish this would be. I need to store an array such as:

```
['hello', 'world', 'love']
```

Inside one column in a table. I do not want to create a new table where each value in the array becomes a separate row. Is there a better way? I guess my biggest concern is performance.

So when creating the migration for this column, ideally I would insert an array with 3 default/nullable values. Then I can set actual values for the array when needed in my application.

Simple scenario: I have a table called `desk` and I want to store 3 items that are on top of the desk such as `['pencil', 'ruler', 'stapler']`, but I do not want to create a separate table `desk_items` to have a row for each item. Hope this makes sense.

Using Laravel and MYSQL

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not going to do all the work for you, but I will suggest you look at the following :

1. Storing arrays in a database as JSON.
2. Laravel's "casting" of attributes.

Comment: Sidenote. If your concern is performance then keep in mind that queries to find a row which has a specific element in that array will be much slower than if you had them as rows in a related table

Comment: Yea been reading up, hasMany relationship is probably the best way?

Comment: it depends on your use case but yes for a simple association of a row with a set of values that are specific to that row a `hasMany` relationship is the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make desc table as jsonb format

```
$table->jsonb('desk');
```

and in model use casts

```
protected $casts = [
    'desk' => 'array',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the array in Database table you should send it with `json_encode` .

```
$data = new Data; 
$data->Name = json_encode($request->DataName);
$data->save();
```

Thus, you can store an array in the name column of your data table.
to use this data you need to call the data with `json_decode`.

```
 $data = json_decode(Data::find(1)->Name);
```

Comment: @Etra This is not the best option for Laravel. You will always have to do json_decode wherever you output this data